# Flask Admin: extra_js and url_for

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to load a script on a certain ModelView in my admin pages:

```
class CustomView(ModelView):
    # Neither approach works here:
    # with current_app.app_context(), current_app.test_request_context():
    extra_js = [url_for('static', filename='admin/admin.js')]
```

With the `app_context()` commented out, I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application
>   context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context
>   is available.

Uncommenting the app_context gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. This typically
>   means that you attempted to use functionality that needed to interface
>   with the current application object in some way. To solve this, set up
>   an application context with app.app_context(). See the documentation
>   for more information.

I also tried adding context when I set up the Admin views, but get the same error:

```
# ADMIN
with app.app_context():
    admin = Admin(app, name='Custom', template_mode='bootstrap3', index_view=MyIndex(), base_template='admin/base.html')
    admin.add_view(CustomView(User, db.session))
```

So, how can I pass the app context appropriately to load my script for this view?

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution, I am not sure it answers perfectly your need, but as long as I felt on this topic by googling my problem I hope this can help fellows.

So, in order to make **url_for** available in flask admin **extra_js** property, I just defined my **extra_js** property in my class that implements the ModelView base class of flask admin by **overriding the render method**.. The snippet equals thousands words:

```
class MyModelView(AdminModelView):

    def render(self, template, **kwargs):
        """
        using extra js in render method allow use
        url_for that itself requires an app context
        """
        self.extra_js = [url_for("static", filename="js/whatever.js")]

        return super(MyModelView, self).render(template, **kwargs)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Just to point out for other noobs. AdminModelView is just the regular ModelView class, that confused me first.

Comment: It's also possible to add it to a single route, for instance if you want to add just to the create route your would do:

class MyModelView(AdminModelView):
    @expose("/new/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
    def create_view(self):
        self.extra_js = [url_for("static", filename="js/whatever.js")]
        return super().create_view()